# Nginx serving Django static files must have folder with same name as URL

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-location, django-staticfiles

I am serving static files using Nginx. My config looks like this:

```
# django settings
STATIC_URL = '/static_folder/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/app_data/'

# nginx config
location /static_folder/ {
    root /app_data/;
}
```

It does not work like this. I need to change the STATIC_ROOT to include the static_folder part. Like this:

```
# django settings
STATIC_URL = '/static_folder/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/app_data/static_folder/' # <-- here

# nginx config
location /static_folder/ {
    root /app_data/;
}
```

I want to be able to serve like this:

```
/app_data/logo.png
instead of this:
/app_data/static_folder/logo.png
```

It is not a big deal if you have one URL part in STATIC_URL but if I use nested URLs, I need to repeat it in STATIC_ROOT too. It gets too deep. For example:

```
# django settings
STATIC_URL = '/static_folder/and/another/folder'
STATIC_ROOT = '/app_data/static_folder/and/another/folder/' 

# nginx config
location /static_folder/ {
    root /app_data/;
}
```

How can I get rid of this and serve files in /app_data/ without including static_url parts in the folder structure.

Comment: What error do you get  with the first code? 404?

Comment: Yes, I get a 404 error code.

Comment: Actually, since you want the end result to be `app_data/file.txt`, shouldn't the `STATIC_URL` and nginx location be 'app_data' also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in your case it has to be `alias`, not `root`:

```
location /static_folder/ {
    alias /app_data/;
}
```